# Helm Kubernetes setup mysql with NodeJs application

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to Kubernetes and helm world and trying to deploy a Nodejs application with a MYSQL database using Kubernetes and Helm on Azure kKubernetes Service.

Here's what I have done so far:

**My `Dockerfile`:**

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 32000
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

I have built the image using this `Dockerfile` and then push it to a repository on my `ACR` registry.
This application is working with `mysql` database, so before installing the helm chart of my application, I have installed the `mysql` helm chart on my cluster using the following command:

```
helm install --name mysql --set mysqlRootPassword=rootpassword,mysqlUser=mysql,mysqlPassword=my-password,mysqlDatabase=mydatabase,persistence.existingClaim=mysql-pvc stable/mysql
```

After that, I have export two variable in the cluster as:

```
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

Then forward the port as a background process like:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/mysql 3306
```

After that I have installed my own application chart, I have created a chart just by running `helm create mychart` and then create a custom `values.yaml` file and pass it on installation, which is as:

```
image:
    registry: helmcr.azurecr.io
    repository: helmcr.azurecr.io/helloworldtest01
    tag: 0.3
service:
    name: http
    type: LoadBalancer
    port: 32000
    internalPort: 32000
hosts:
    - name: mychart.local
      path: /
```

After the installation of both charts, the application should be connected to the `mysql` but it says: `CrashLoopBackOff`

> **Update:** Here's how I have configured the database connection in my

```
application:
module.exports = {
    adapters: {
        mysqlAdapt: mysqlAdapter
    },

  connections: {
    mysqlDB: {
        adapter: 'mysqlAdapt',
        host: process.env.MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST,
        database: 'mydatabase',
        user:'root',
        password:'my-password',
        port: process.env.MMYSQL_SERVICE_PORT,
        supportBigNumbers:true, //true/false
        debug:['ComQueryPacket'], //false or array of node-mysql debug options
        trace:true //true/false
    } 
  }
};
```

When I run the command below to get the logs:

```
kubectl logs myrel09-mychart09-5b8bb86788-9k627 -p
```

here the output of the above command:

```
Wed, 06 Feb 2019 13:29:21 GMT body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares at app.js:10:9
Wed, 06 Feb 2019 13:29:21 GMT body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option at node_modules/body-parser/index.js:105:29
Wed, 06 Feb 2019 13:29:21 GMT express deprecated app.del: Use app.delete instead at node_modules/express-resource/index.js:153:19
Load model crud
(node:1) [DEP0095] DeprecationWarning: timers.enroll() is deprecated. Please use setTimeout instead.

/usr/src/app/app.js:32
    if (err) throw err;
             ^
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at afterwards (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:72:13)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
    at Handshake.onConnect [as _callback] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:54:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:364:14)
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleNetworkError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:421:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

When I try to connect to this `mysql` database from my local system, it's connected successfully, it means the database is working correctly but there's something wrong with my configuration.

What can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The node pod is trying to connect itself, you will need to change that.

Comment: Hi @PaulAnnetts how can I change that?

Comment: That depends on your helm deployment of your service which you did not share and details of mysql helm which I do not know. But it cannot be 127.0.0.1 which is the loopback local address. I would recommend you research how kubernetes networking works and the details of the mysql helm chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using same cluster to deploy both applications, you can use cluster ip as well.

If you want to use port forward, I think you should use ip of your node not localhost ip.

Comment: Hi @RajeshDeshpande, do I need to export my `pod ip` as `MYSQL_HOST` and then need to use it inside my application?

Comment: If you create db service before creating application pods, it will be available my default. First deploy mysql charts and them application charts.  Then go to application container, you will see mysql service details. No need to export anything. This is nothing but service discovery by environment variables.

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same thing, first deploy the application chart then deploying the `mysql` chart but what `host` i need to define in my application for connection?

Comment: Order matters. First deploy mysql chart and then application.  So that mysql service host and port will be available in application container. If you follow this need not to export any variable

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services

Comment: So, in this case do I still need `port-forwarding` ?

Comment: No.. Use that service ip and port

Comment: So, I will user service ip as `mysql host` and service port as `mysql port`?

Comment: Yes. Never expose backed pods to everyone. Always user cluster ip service for them.

Comment: My SQL service name is `mysql`, so now I'm using `MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST` as database host and `MMYSQL_SERVICE_PORT` as database port in my application.

Comment: Hi @ RajeshDeshpande, still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you ping MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST from application container and check of it works.

Comment: I run this command `kubectl exec -it myrel09-mychart09-7f6df6bc8c-l4gqr ping MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST` but it returns nothing!

Comment: Sometime it returns `ping: bad address 'MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST'`

Comment: Hi @RajeshDeshpande, it's working now but taking long time, after few minutes the application pod change the state from `CrashLoopBackOff` to `running`.

Comment: It should not take time as you are using cluster ip . Reason might be pod crashing. Troubleshoot Pod with   kubectl describe pod <POD_NAME>.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh Deshpande, now it's returning this error:  `Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'10.244.1.8' (using password: YES)` now even I'm not able to connect this database from my side which was previously working.